# Applying encoding to train and test data separately

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a feature in my dataset `State`, so after splitting I apply encoding to train set like this

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(drop='first', handle_unknown='ignore'), ['State'])], remainder='passthrough')
encoded_X_train = ct.fit_transform(X_train)
```

and train model like this

```
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(encoded_X_train, y_train)
```

then encodes and predict like this

```
encoded_X_test = ct.fit_transform(X_test)
y_pred = regressor.predict(encoded_X_test)
```

Is this the right process of doing so, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No. You should train the encoding model using the train data only.
`fit_transform` is transforming data based on the model fitted with the data.

Thus, you should use the following code instead.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(drop='first', handle_unknown='ignore'), ['State'])], remainder='passthrough')
encoded_X_train = ct.fit_transform(X_train)
encoded_X_test = ct.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: Thank you, this clarified my doubt of over-fitting. Just one more question how can I measure the accuracy of my model. I have seen in some places score method is used to measure accuracy, any link will be appreciated.